# Allowing cors on express 4

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have an express app that i want to use as a web socket server with socket io. This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myhotel:server');
var http = require('http');
var socket = require("socket.io");

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */


// Socket setup
const io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("Made socket connection");
});

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

This works but when i try connecting a client, i get a CORS error. I am needed to allow cors and this is what i have

```
io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
      cors: {
        origin: '*',
      }
    });
```

This is my socket setup

```
// Socket setup
const io = socket(server);
```

How can i allow the cors object above in my socket setup above?.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way

```
// Socket setup
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3007",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

`io.set` and `io.origins` no longer work when setting cors policy on `"socket.io": "^4.1.2",`